# Troubleshooting no boot from old windows 98 embedded machine

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, memory-error

I work for a manufacturing company and one of our quality devices is a photometer.  This photometer is hooked up to an Advantech IPC-6806 WHB-20Z running Windows 98 Embedded.  We suffered a power outage over the weekend and now the machine will no longer boot up.  We pulled it off the floor to diagnose and found that it was giving us a beep code where it just beeps in a slow, steady rhythm.  I pulled the main board to try and figure out what the BIOS is so I could track down what the beep code means.  The main board is a PCA-6178VE ([user manual I'm using](http://advdownload.advantech.com/productfile/Downloadfile3/1+GC+4077/PCA-6178_Manual.pdf)) which connects into a [backplane](http://advdownload.advantech.com/productfile/Downloadfile3/1-1RZDI7/2002610631_PCA-6106P3-0C1_User%27s_Note_ed.2.pdf) and I found [this site](https://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm) which says that the beep should be the RAM.  Since it was only a single stick of 128MB PC100 RAM we bought a new stick and had it overnighted.  We put in the new ram and got the same beep code.

Now I'm at the point where I don't know what to do.  I could order more RAM in case the stick we got was DOA.  I've found the board and CPU on Ebay so I could order that but they all ship from china and won't be here for 2-4 weeks.  Is there anything I'm missing in diagnosing this? Should I get more RAM just in case or does it sound like it is the board, not the RAM that is the issue?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the CMOS settings (J1)? Move the jumper from 1-2 to 2-3 for a few seconds while the system is plugged in (not turned on), then put it back. Does it allow the system to boot?

Comment: @CanadianLuke That did not help.

Comment: Can you take a volt-meter to the pins on the power supply? Ensure you're getting 3.3V, 5V and 12V as required? I'm not sure if the power supply is new enough that it needs a physical switch to turn the system on instead of momentary contact, but there are diagrams on Google of what voltages should be coming out of which pins

Comment: @CanadianLuke It's an old school, manual switch for the power.  I'll need to find the pinout for the plug but in the mean time I noticed that on the adapter board there are power LED's and the +3.3V and the 5VSB are not light up.

Comment: That's my next thought is the power supply. Usually, the wires are colour-coded, so that will help you figure out what to expect

Comment: @CanadianLuke I got the specs and check all of the voltages.  It is using an AT connector with only +-5 and +-12 volts and those all check out at +-4.9/5.0 and +-11.9/12.0.

Comment: There is an area on the backplane for an ATX power supply. Do you have a spare one to try?

Comment: I believe so.  I'll give that a try.

Comment: @CanadianLuke Just an update.  Tried another PS, same results.  We are deciding now on just buying a new machine or getting used parts from China.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was either the CPU or the main board.  We ruled out the RAM and power supply so that left just those two components.

In order to save ourselves some trouble We ordered a used replacement that came with a CPU just in case and were able to drop it into the chassis and it posted and booted without issue.

There were many revisions to this board and it comes with or without Ethernet so we made sure we got the exact same revision and it had Ethernet since that is what our original had.